# Can you explain/simplify this regular expression (PCRE) in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

```
preg_match('/.*MyString[ (\/]*([a-z0-9\.\-]*)/i', $contents, $matches);
```

I need to debug this one. I have a good idea of what it's doing but since I was never an expert at regular expressions I need your help.

Can you tell me what it does block by block (so I can learn)?

Does the syntax can be simplified (I think there is no need to escape the dot with a slash)?

Comment: The dot is a wildcard unless escaped. Lemme try to sift through it and  break it down for ya...

Comment: In a character class, dot (period) does not need to be escaped. I think backslash does, though.

Comment: http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws

Comment: [This site](http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws) will tell you block by block what it does (there are hundreds of others like it)

Comment: [**Go to this site (http://www.regexper.com/)**](http://www.regexper.com/) and type in `/.*MyString[ (\/]*([a-z0-9\.\-]*)/`

Comment: [Learn about regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), and be sure to read up on the PHP [PCRE extension](http://php.net/pcre). Figure it out by helping yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regexp...

```
'/.*MyString[ (\/]*([a-z0-9\.\-]*)/i'
```

`.*` matches any character zero or more times

`MyString` matches that string. But you are using case insensitive matching so the matched string will spell "mystring" by but with any capitalization

EDIT: (Thanks to Alan Moore) `[ (\/]*`. This matches any of the chars `space` `(` or `/` repeated zero of more times. As Alan points out the final escape of `/` is to stop the `/` being treated as a regexp delimeter.

EDIT: The `(` does *not* need escaping and neither does the `.` (thanks AlexV) because:

> All non-alphanumeric characters other than \, -, ^ (at the start) and
>   the terminating ] are non-special in character classes, but it does no
>   harm if they are escaped.
>   -- http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php

The hyphen, generally does need to be escaped, otherwise it will try to define a range. For example:

```
[A-Z]  // matches all upper case letters of the aphabet
[A\-Z] // matches 'A', '-', and 'Z'
```

However, where the hyphen is at the end of the list you can get away with not escaping it (but always best to be in the habit of escaping it... I got caught out by this].

`([a-z0-9\.\-]*)` matches any string containing the characters a through z (note again this is effected by the case insensitive match), 0 through 9, a dot, a hyphen, repeated zero of more times. The surrounding `()` capture this string. This means that `$matches[1]` will contain the string matches by `[a-z0-9\.\-]*`. The brackets `()` tell `preg_match` to "capture" this string.

e.g.

```
<?php
  $input = "aslghklfjMyString(james321-james.org)blahblahblah";
  preg_match('/.*MyString[ (\/]*([a-z0-9.\-]*)/i', $input, $matches);
  print_r($matches);
?>
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => aslghklfjMyString(james321-james.org
    [1] => james321-james.org
)
```

Note that because you use a case insensitive match...

```
$input = "aslghklfjmYsTrInG(james321898-james.org)blahblahblah";
```

Will also match and give the same answer in `$matches[1]`

Hope this helps....

Comment: `[ (\/]` is perfectly valid.  The forward slash is not a regex metacharacter and usually doesn't need escaping.  But it has to be escaped this time because he's using it as his regex delimiter.

Comment: @Jimbo @Alan Moore Does the dot and dash really need to be backslash escaped in: `[a-z0-9\.\-]*`?

Comment: @Avexv: The hyphen does have to be escaped because otherwise it will define a range (unless right at then end as in this case). I think you might be right about the dot too! Just tested... does work if the dot is not escaped and agrees with the quote from php.net... good point

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down step-by step, removing the explained parts from the expression.

```
"/.*MyString[ (\/]*([a-z0-9\.\-]*)/i"
```

Let's first strip the regex delimiters (/i at the end means it's case-insensitive):

```
".*MyString[ (\/]*([a-z0-9\.\-]*)"
```

Then we've got a wildcard lookahead (search for any symbol any number of times until we match the next statement.

```
"MyString[ (\/]*([a-z0-9\.\-]*)"
```

Then match 'MyString' literally, followed by any number (note the '*') of any of the following: ' ', '(', '/'. This is probably the error zone, you need to escape that '('. Try [ (/].

```
"([a-z0-9\.\-]*)"
```

Then we get a capture group for any number of any of the following: a-z literals, 0-9 digits, '.', or '-'.

That's pretty much all of it.